# Solr -- Could not find collection

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I'm trying to index a sample data set using Solrj-client 4.10.3 locally on my laptop with 2 solr instances and 1 standalone ZooKeeper instance.
I have a standalone instance of Zookeeper listening at client port 2182.
I have 2 solr instances running locally on port 7500 and 8500.
I created a collection with 2 shards 1 replication factor across these successfully. Now when I try to run my indexing program (SolrCloudServer), I keep getting a error stating: 
Could not find collection : collection-name

I've verified that the collection was successfully created and can see so via the solr-cloud admin web-UI

Can anyone suggest what is it that I'm missing here?

Thanks :)

Comment: Post your indexing code with the stacktrace of the error.

Comment: @BinoyDalal: I can't post all the code here unfortunately. But I can tell you that I'm using a instance of CloudSolrServer with a LBHttpSolrServer instance.  Here's a snippet ---  cloudSolrServer = new CloudSolrServer(zkHost, lbSolrServer);
        cloudSolrServer.setRequestWriter(new BinaryRequestWriter());
        cloudSolrServer.setDefaultCollection(_collectionName);
        cloudSolrServer.setIdField("uuid"); ------ Then I create a batch of solr documents and add them --- cloudSolrServer.add(_fmipBatch); I'm not concerned with hard commit as I'm using auto-commit.

Comment: Okay so I found a solution and will be answering the question myself. --- Turns out I was using an older solrj-client library and that resulted in older zookeeper code trying to get clusterstate.json. However, Solr 5.1 apparently maintains a state.json per collection and doesn't update clusterstate.json anymore which resulted in collection not found error.